# Detect iOS8 Reachability Gesture

Tags: ios, ios8, gestures, iphone-6

Any ways to detect the new *Reachability* gesture of iOS8 in Objective-C?

The gesture is activated double tapping the TouchID button on the iPhone6 and iPhone6Plus.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no public APIs for it.

There are [two related private API methods on `UIApplication`](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIApplication.h) I can find (using either of these should get your app rejected from the App Store):

- `_setReachabilitySupported:`, which presumably would en/disable reachability (like Spotlight)
- `_deactivateReachability`, which would return the view to the normal place on the screen

I don't see anything that informs your application that the user has performed the gesture, however.

---

You could also experiment with subclassing `UIWindow` and overriding `setFrame:`. Set a breakpoint in this method, and if it fires when you enable Reachability, you can look at the stack trace for more information.