# iOS 9 event for lightly double tapping home button i.e. Reachability?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, home-button

Is there an event or way to know when the user taps the home button twice lightly for iOS9?

Just to be clear that you know what I am talking about; I am not talking about when the user double taps the home button to then choose another app to jump into but for iPhone 6 and 6 plus where you can double tap the home button lightly so that the whole screen slides down so that you can reach the top buttons easier. I believe this is called Reachability.

How would you access this in swift code?
Thanks!

Comment: I presume you're talking about [this](http://i.imgur.com/AWFeM1c.png)? I.e. **Reachability**.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am talking about.

Comment: Take a look at this response: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26371321/2929590

Comment: Alright, Thanks Igor. That is a shame that this event isn't accessible.